# Building Android AVD

Tags: android

I can't seem to get my AVD built.

I got all the tools. I even have GIT, but when I try to do the command `avd devices` it will say: `no such command`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to issue the `adb` command in the `tools` directory where you have installed Android.

For me it's

```
f:\android-sdk-windows-1.6_r1\tools\adb.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `tools` directory in the SDK to your Windows `PATH`.

`Control Panel`/`System`/`Advanced System Settings`/`Environment Variables`, select `PATH`, click `Edit...`, and add `;c:\Program Files\android-sdk\tools` (adjusted for wherever you actually installed the tools) to the end. If you want to make this change only for your current user, and there is no `PATH` in the `User variables` box, just add it as a new variable and leave out the semicolon.